# XLIFF localization tools for Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring, xliff

Xcode 6 introduced a new localization workflow which uses the open .XLIFF format. Xcode extracts the strings from NSLocalizedString, strings in storyboards / XIB files and creates a single XLIFF file for each localization.

**I'm looking for good localization tools that translators can use to open and edit the files exported by Xcode.**

The translated file needs to be saved as .XLIFF and then imported into Xcode. Xcode creates a new localization for the target language specified in the XLIFF file or updates the existing localization.

Which localization tool(s) do you recommend?

Comment: Don't really have an answer, but when this was released, Apple claimed the major translators already supported this format. Might be worth reaching out to them to see what they use.

Comment: According to the [CAT Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation#Some_notable_CAT_tools) Wikipedia article almost all tools claim XLIFF support.

Comment: But many need a tool for John Doe the unknown student translator on fiverr. For sure the large 10x as expensive professional translating companies already support it.

Answer (score 8):

XLIFF is introduced some years ago and there's bunch of tools which support XLIFF.

- [OmegaT](http://www.omegat.org/en/omegat.html)
- [iLocalize](http://www.arizona-software.ch/ilocalize/)
- [EvilTrans](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eviltrans/)
- [CounterParts lite](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/counterparts-lite/id711576477?l=en&mt=12)
- [Open Language Tools](https://java.net/projects/open-language-tools)
- [MemSource](http://www.memsource.com)
- [Virtaal](http://virtaal.translatehouse.org)
- [SwordFish](http://www.maxprograms.com/products/swordfish.html)
- [XTM Intl (web)](http://xtm-intl.com)
- [Pootle](http://pootle.translatehouse.org)
- [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com)
- [Linguan](http://linguanapp.com/)

Comment: I haven't check them all in detail, but my choice was CounterParts. I requested a trial, and it's pretty neat. (I am not affiliated with the product in any way, but the OP asked for a recommendation).

Comment: With iLocalize and XCode 6 you get missing original attribute errors and import stops :-(

Answer (score 3):

[Free online XLIFF editor](http://xliff.brightec.co.uk/)

You can read more info [here](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/free-online-xliff-editor).

Comment: Works but terrible usage. Makes translation twice or three times as expensive.

Comment: Bad service. Used it a little.

Answer (score 2):

Just found few on App Store :

- [Counterparts Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/counterparts-lite/id711576477?mt=12)
- [Xliffie](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/xliffie/id961651406?mt=12)
- [Linguan](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/linguan/id477163052?mt=12)
- [iXLIFF](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/ixliff/id944658897?mt=12)

Answer (score 2):

[XLIFFTool](https://itunes.apple.com/si/app/xlifftool/id1074282695?mt=12) Is a **FREE** simple and woking editor. Easy installed via AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

[Heartsome's GPL XLIFF editor](https://github.com/heartsome/translationstudio8) is the most complete and standard compliant solution. It used to be a closed tool but they released the code under the GPL a while ago.